# AOP x IoC for caching

Tags: caching, inversion-of-control, aop

Do you prefer the clean approach of an AOP cache layer on top of your methods (any DAO or service method) OR do you prefer the total control approach of injecting a cache instance wherever you need?

I understand AOP gives you loose coupling and separation of concerns, but not so much flexibility, unless you are coding the method interceptors yourself.

I tend to like the IoC approach, because a cache instance can be easily mocked if you need to and with an instance of the cache you have total control and flexibility.

It is like logging. Who actually uses AOP for application wide logging?

Answer (score 0):

This is the question about should we use "real" AOP at all (by "real" I mean *quantification* and *obliviousness*, so that you can enable aspects globally and 100% transparently for the system). My opinion is to avoid that 100% transparent solutions every time you can. If you're at the development stage, it will be better to design your system in the way that don't force you to do tricks like AOP weaving at intermediate code level.

At the other hand, it will be quite disturbing to write caching concern for every component/interface you need, no matter how you'll do it. The most obvious way which came to my mind is to have a caching Decorator class for each cached class - one thing done many times.

So the path I will try to follow is to have an idea of AOP done using some IoC extension based on dynamic proxying. When fetching an object from IoC, container can check in its configuration should the cache be applied for given type and if so, create an interface-based dynamic proxy with caching. This solution is not forcing you to write a lot of similar code and is less confusing than "real" AOP by its visibility in the source code. There are some implementations like this, but you haven't specified any language, so I can't offer any.

Comment: The Unity IOC container can support AOP through different types of method interceptors.  Checkout MSDN.